# How to subclass SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclass

I get these errors and I don't know how to fix them. I want to create SKScene with fixed size like this:

```
width: screenWidth
height: screenHeight/10
```

I don't know how to subclass SKScene in a correct way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening as you're trying to access properties before the class has initialised.

If you move that to after the `super.init` line, it'll work e.g.:

```
...
super.init(size: fixedSize)
self.name = name
self.buttons = buttons
```

*edit* Just thought, there is an exception to this though and I've just confirmed this. Playground doesn't like it, but an actual app does:

class someClass: NSObject {

```
    let a = 2
    var b = 3

    override init(){
        let c = self.a
        let d = self.b
        super.init()
        print("c: \(c), d:\(d)")
    }

    func foo(){
        print("bar \(a)")
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have values that you want to apply BEFORE the init, then it's best to assign the as `static let myVar = 123`

Comment: I've just added an exception to the case in my original answer. As to why playground crashes, but the app runs, I have no idea, but I assume this is because the values have defaults.

Comment: Don't `name` and `buttons` need to be initialized before invoking `super.init(size: fixedSize)`? According to the class docs: "Safety check 1 A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer."

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

```
init(buttons: Button) {
        self.buttons = buttons
        super.init()
        let fixedSize = CGSize.init(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight/10)
        super.size = fixedSize
    }
```

I removed "name" because I don't need it anymore. I moved `self.buttons = buttons` because it needs to be set before `super.init()`

Comment: In regards to using screen sizes etc... Don't forget to use the scaling to ensure that retina etc.. is covered... `UIscreen.mainscreen().scale` e.g. this handles returns @2x @3x etc.. sizes.